# How to Create a Restful service for already available site

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat7

I have some API web site which will generate some JSON data but I can't access that data directly with that URL (if I try to access it says oauth error) so for that I have a secret key and lib file which throws that exception.

So I want to create a Restful web service for that ,...

without the restful service, I am accessing the data from a class file which invoked in main() method and if I run it as  java application I am getting data at console,.. hence it has main method,.. 
but I need to build a Restful web service,. and retrieve the data in mobile windows/iPhone/android

I know what is Restful service But I don't know how get that data java file data,.. which is at console,...to Restful service

Comment: Can you please give some more information about the setup of that what you have now? Is it a servlet based web-app or something else, because I'm not getting that. Because if you say that you have an api where you get some JSON data, but with authentication, that seems like some kind of service, right?

Comment: Yes, sir,.. its a servlet based web-app(Restful web-service),.. in that data is already available from another site so i need to link or mirror that site,.. with my key,.. i am getting data from a url like xx.api.xxxxxx/v1/"my query" what ever i gives in my my query it will generate from that API site,.. but right now i am getting the query output to my console,.. on a java main() method,.. so i want that output to a Restful service,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

you have code the below stuff in your webservice method

```
public String myMethos(){

        String urlString="http://example.com/WS/StaticExample.php?method=sayHello&name=World";
        URL url=new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection=url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.close();
        JSONObject jsonobj = null;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String decodedString="",URLstrJson="";

        while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
          URLstrJson+=decodedString;
        }
```

Say your value of URLstrJson is as shown below

```
{
"worldpopulation":
[
{
"rank":1,
"country":"China",
"population":"1,354,040,000",
"flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/china.png"
}
]
}
```

Then,

```
    jsonobj=new JSONObject(URLstrJson);

    System.out.println(jsonobj.toString());
    return jsonobj.toString();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

With what I percieve from your problem, you can write a wrapper REST class which calls your current methods and send back the response to user. Elaborating it, say your current class is A and its method is getData(), which is currently called from main method. Now you create a REST class with a method say data() and within this function you are just doing return A.getData(). 
Other configurations like annotations, param types etc. you can add as per you needs.

Comment: Thanks for the Response sir,. i understand your answer sir,.. if i use wrapper class, will it get data from main() method to Restful web-service,.. if so.. please can you provide any tutorial or example,... its need because that site is running but i need to create just like a  mirror which generates all process of that API,..

Comment: You may check http://nuteck.wordpress.com/category/web-services/. Just modify getDate() function as String date = new A().getData();
return Response.status(200).entity(date).build();